# communication between browser and local application

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, air, communication

Is it possible that a window of a local Air(actionscript3)-application is automatically being aligned to a browser window? Can I therefore access the position/size of a browser through actionscript ?
(on a Mac)
What are common approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to align to a certain page and you can place an swf there - it's possible: an swf in a browser will have to call external js to know the browser window position and size and then pass it to standalone app through `LocalConnection`